# ViewPagerAdapter and LiveData

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter, android-livedata

I have a ViewPagerAdapter with a page for each day and a ListView for each page. I'm trying to hook LiveData into it.

Right now, it's doing this:

***Opens app***

*I/OnCreateView: startDate = 1608958800 items.size() = 0*

*I/OnCreateView: startDate = 1608786000 items.size() = 0*

*I/OnChanged: startDate = 1608786000 items.size() = 2*

*I/OnChanged: startDate = 1608786000 items.size() = 2*

I see today's list, which should have 2 items, and it is accurate.

***Swipes right***

*I/OnCreateView: startDate = 1607922000 items.size() = 2*

*I/OnChanged: startDate = 1607922000 items.size() = 2*

I see the previous day's list, which should have 4 items, and it has today's list.

***Swipes right again***

*I/OnCreateView: startDate = 1607835600 items.size() = 0*

*I/OnChanged: startDate = 1607835600 items.size() = 0*

I see the day before yesterday, which should have 4 items, and it's empty.

***Swipes left***

*I/OnCreateView: startDate = 1608958800 items.size() = 0*

*I/OnChanged: startDate = 1608958800 items.size() = 0*

Yesterday's list still has today's data.

***Swipes left again***

No logs and today's list is destroyed.

Here's some code from my Fragment:

```
        if (bundle != null) {
            sTitle = bundle.getString("title");
            setTitle(sTitle);
            year = 1900 + bundle.getInt("year");
            month = bundle.getInt("month");
            day = bundle.getInt("day");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
            startDate = (int) (calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L);
        }

        dataViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new dataViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication(), startDate)).get(dataViewModel.class);

        List<listItems> items = dataViewModel.getDataByDate().getValue();
        if (items == null)
            items = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.i("OnCreateView", "startDate = " + startDate + " items.size() = " + items.size());
        MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), items);

        theListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        dataViewModel.getDataByDate().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<data>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<listItems> data) {
                List<listItems> items = data;
                if (items == null)
                    items = new ArrayList<>();
                Log.i("OnChanged", "startDate = " + startDate + " items.size() = " + items.size());
                adapter.setExercises(items);
            }
        });
```

From my MyArrayAdapter:

```
public void setExercises(List<listItems> mListItems) {
    this.clear();
    this.addAll(mListItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public class DataViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private Repository repository;
    Integer startDate;
    public static LiveData<List<listItems>> mItems = null;

    public DataViewModel(Application application, Integer startDate) {
        super(application);
        this.startDate = startDate;
        repository = new Repository(application);
    }

    public LiveData<List<listItems>> getDataByDate() {
        if (mItems == null) {
            mItems = repository.getDataByDate(startDate);
        }
        return mItems;
    }

}
```

And my ViewModelFactory:

```
public class DataViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private Application mApplication;
    private Integer mParam;
    
    public DataViewModelFactory(Application application, Integer param) {
        mApplication = application;
        mParam = param;
    }
    
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new DataViewModel(mApplication, mParam);
    }
}
```

And from my BaseActivity:

```
public void ShowCards(Map<Integer, Long> map, Class<?> fragment) {

    Log.i("BaseActivity", "ShowCards" );

    Integer started;
    Long id;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        started = entry.getKey();
        id = entry.getValue();

        Log.i("BaseActivity: ShowCards", "started(" + started + ") id (" + id + ") [3]");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(started * 1000L);

        addPage(id, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), fragment);

    }

}


public void addPage(Long id, int year, int month, int day, Class<?> fragment) {
    Log.i("BaseActivity", "addPage: fragment: " + fragment.getName());
    Log.i("BaseActivity", "addPage: id: " + id);
    Log.i("BaseActivity", "addPage: year: " + year);
    Log.i("BaseActivity", "addPage: month: " + month);
    Log.i("BaseActivity", "addPage: day: " + day);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);    //TODO: Put dateFormat in the string table.
    Date date = new Date(year, month, day);
    String pagename = sdf.format(date);
    bundle.putString("title", pagename);
    bundle.putInt("year", year);
    bundle.putInt("month", month);
    bundle.putInt("day", day);
    bundle.putLong("id", id);
    BaseFragment myFragment = null;
    try {
        myFragment = (BaseFragment) fragment.newInstance();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("BaseActivity", "addPage: myFragment: " + myFragment.toString() + " bundle = " + bundle.toString() + "[4]");
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(myFragment, pagename, id);
    viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.i("BaseActivity: addPage", "viewPageAdapter.getCount() = " + viewPagerAdapter.getCount());

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);

}
```

And my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Long> mFragmentIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title, Long Id) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        mFragmentIdList.add(Id);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Can you also provide the source of `MyArrayAdapter`? It feels like that is a likely culprit…

Comment: Also show your `ViewPagerAdapter` code to show your fragment creation as it feels like something could be wrong there are normally viewpager only creates first page +/- 1 and may be your fragements are getting mixed up.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick responses. I added some logs to hopefully clarify things. @Andrew I'll add more code if you like, but I think the culprit is somewhere in my ViewModel or ViewModelFactory. None of the lists should have 0 items, and why does the list for 1608786000 have 0 items when created and then change to 2 items?

Comment: @RedBassett MyArrayAdapter source is https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3426

Comment: "and why does the list for 1608786000 have 0 items when created and then change to 2 items" ViewPager manages the fragments lifecycle and LiveData is lifecycle aware. The way I read you logs is - App opens Viewpager creates Fragment 1 (tomorrow) and 0 (today)  brings them to created lifecycle level, then it starts and then resumes fragment 0 (today). As livedata is only active in started and resumed states you see the log for on changed. So a swipe right on a normal viewpager should do nothing (you are at page 0 and it won't go -1). But without all the viewpager stuff it is hard to tell

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your help. I've added the code that adds the pages to my viewPagerAdapter.

Comment: Was really after the constructor of `viewPagerAdapter` class to see what adapter class you are extending and what behaviour options you are using (if any), also it's `getItem` method on how you are returning fragments for it to display and as you have shown that you are updating the set of fragments it is to display then show `addFrag` method. It might be worth logging in the Fragment the `onStar`, `onStop`, `onResume` and `onPause` Lifecycle events with a meaningful identifier like `title` or `startDate` as this might be and interaction of the Fragments lifecycle with LiveData

Comment: @Andrew It looks like I'm extending the FragmentStatePagerAdapter after all. Code added.